# How to access context in repository [MVVM]

Tags: java, android, mvvm, dagger-2

I am developing an Android application that makes use of the MVVM architecture. My problem is that my repository (that is responsible for fetching JSON from the web) needs access to a context.

I've read several suggestions on StackOverflow. So far the most reasonable options I've gathered are the following:

- Use Dagger 2 to somehow inject the context.
- Let my `ViewModel` extend from `AndroidViewModel` to get the application context and pass that to the repo.

As of right now I have one `ViewModel` and one `Repo`

RoomFragmentViewModel.java:

```java
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<List<JSONObject>> rooms;
    private Repository repository;

    public void init(){
        if(rooms != null){
            return;
        }
        repository = repository.getInstance();
        rooms = repository.getRooms();
    }
```

Repository.java:

```java
public class Repository {

    private static Repository instance;
    private ArrayList<JSONObject> actualRooms = new ArrayList<>();


    public static Repository getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Repository();
        }
        return instance;
    }

   
    public MutableLiveData<List<JSONObject>> getRooms() {
        ...
    }

    private void setRooms() {
        ...
        // Here I am fetching data from my server, but in order to to do so I require a context

        String url = "http://10.0.0.5:8000/api";

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {...

        // Context needs to be provided right here:
        MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);

    }
}
```

Due to contradictory statements on the Internet I am unsure how I should resolve this problem. If your answer makes use of dagger could you be so nice to provide an explanation with code since I am completely new to dagger. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Of those two, I would go the dependency injection/service locator route.

Comment: you don't have to use dagger (if you don't know how to) alternatively, what you could do, is initialize `MySingleton` in your Application class and then just use it throughout with the context of the application

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you provide more help in regards to the DI approach. Because I have a ViewModel in between my Fragment and my Repository injecting the context seems quite sophisticated.

Comment: Well, I am not a Dagger expert, so I can't easily help with that. I use Kotlin and Koin.

Comment: I see. Well thank you anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up injecting the context via dagger. However, from my point of view making your `ViewModel` extend from `AndroidViewModel` is also an valid option and definitely the easier one. If I were developing an simple and small application I would probably recommend just extending from `AndroidViewModel` to avoid unnecessary boilerplate code from dagger.

I followed the dagger series from codingwithmith in order to implement my own solution.
So his channel might be useful for future readers:
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoNZZLhPuuRteu02rh7bzsw/featured

Comment: In this way, You will end up with an integrated testing solution for your ViewModel. Thus, injecting context is not boilerplate.

Answer (score 3):

Using Android Hilt

```
//Dagger - Hilt
def hilt_version = "2.31.2-alpha"
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"

def hilt_viewmodel_version = "1.0.0-alpha03"
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:$hilt_viewmodel_version"
kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:$hilt_viewmodel_version"
```

.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideContext(application: Application): Context = application.applicationContext
}
```

Then pass it via constructor

```
class MyRepository @Inject constructor(private val context: Context) {
...
}
```